# Правильный порядок вызова деструкторов и создание объекта в автоматической памяти при реализации полиморфизма

Tags: c++, классы, полиморфизм

Добрый вечер, имеется пара вопросов по полиморфизму.

### 1 вопрос:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Human{
  protected:
    string name;
    int age;
    char sex;
  public:
  /* v Ваш код v */
  Human(string name, int age, char sex) {
    this-> name = name;
    this-> age = age;
    this-> sex = sex;
    cout << "контструктор Human" << endl;
  }

    virtual void Show() {
      cout << name << endl << age << endl << sex << endl;
    }

    virtual ~Human() {
        cout << "виртуальный деструктор Human" << endl;
    }

};

class Coder: public Human{
  protected:
    float IQ;
  public:
  /* v Ваш код v */
  Coder(string name, int age, char sex, float IQ):Human(name, age, sex) {
    this-> IQ = IQ;
    cout << "конструктор Coder" << endl;
  }

  void Show() {
    cout << IQ << endl;
  }

  ~Coder() {
      cout << "виртуальный деструктор Coder" << endl;
  }

};

int main(){

  setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
  Human *human = new Human("Tom", 21, 'M');
  Human *coder = new Coder("Alice", 19, 'F', 150.6f);
  human->Show();
  coder->Show();

  delete human;
  delete coder;
  return 0;
}

/*
Консоль:
конструктор Human
конструктор Human
конструктор Coder
Tom
21
M
150.6
виртуальный деструктор Human
виртуальный деструктор Coder
виртуальный деструктор Human
*/
```

Как известно, уничтожение объекта базового класса влечет за собой уничтожение объекта производного класса, поэтому виртуальный деструктор производного объекта должен выполняться перед деструктором базового объекта.

Поэтому в данном случае объекты должны удаляться в таком порядке:

```
  delete coder;
  delete human;
```

Или же порядок удаления не имеет значения, поскольку это 2 разных объекта?

т.е. при создании объекта наследника - сначала вызывается конструктор базы потом наследника, а при создании объекта базы - вызывается конструктор базы и порядок удаления объектов не имеет значения как и порядок их создания.

И фраза "уничтожение объекта базового класса влечет за собой уничтожение объекта производного класса" касается только когда речь заходит о полиморфизме?

т.е. в случае с `delete coder` эта фраза имеет смысл, тк объект наследника удаляется через указатель на базовый класс, поэтому используется виртуальный деструктор

а в случае с `delete human` - объект базового класса удаляется из динамической памяти, поэтому используется не виртуальный деструктор, а обычный деструктор, который в данном случае определен в теле класса как виртуальный

Путаница возникла из-за того, что если создать эти объекты в автоматической памяти, то деструкторы вызываются в логичном порядке (по принципу последним пришёл — первым ушёл):

```
  Human h("Tom", 21, 'M');
  Human *human = &h;
  Coder c("Alice", 19, 'F', 150.6f);
  Human *coder = &c;
  human->Show();
  coder->Show();

/*
Консоль:
конструктор Human
конструктор Human
конструктор Coder
Tom
21
M
150.6
виртуальный деструктор Coder
виртуальный деструктор Human
виртуальный деструктор Human
*/
```

### 2 вопрос:

Для реализации полиморфизма можно:

создать объект наследника в динамической памяти:

```
Human *p = new Coder;
```

создать объект наследника в автоматической памяти:

```
Coder obj;
Human *p = &obj;
```

Тут у меня возникло противоречие, полиморфизм достигается только с помощью позднего связывания, а значит объект необходимо создавать именно в динамической памяти с помощью оператора `new`, ибо именно во время выполнения программы компилятор анализирует тип объекта, на который указывает указатель, чтобы определить какую реализацию виртуального метода следует вызвать, во время запуска программы этого еще неизвестно.

В связи с чем вопрос - почему создание объекта в автоматической памяти считается корректным для реализации полиморфизма?

Comment: Какая-то каша. Ничего не понятно, что вы хотите спросить.

Comment: «Как известно, уничтожение объекта базового класса влечет за собой уничтожение объекта производного класса» — что, простите?

Comment: Прошу прощения, невдумчиво написал. Имел ввиду, что виртуальный деструктор производного объекта должен быть вызван перед деструктором базового объекта, чтобы произошло правильное удаление производного объекта через указатель на его базовый класс.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Ответ на ваш первый вопрос вы дали сами: это два совершенно независимых объекта и какой-то "порядок вызова деструкторов" у них есть только "внутри", свой для каждого объекта в отдельности. Поэтому не имеет никакого значения, в каком порядке вы будете удалять эти объекты - они друг на друга никак не влияют.
- Ваш второй вопрос основан на неясной/неверной посылке *"полиморфизм достигается только с помощью позднего связывания, а значит объект необходимо создавать именно в динамической памяти"*. Это откуда вы такое взяли?

  "Позднее связывание" в С++ означает, по определению, только то, что при вызове виртуального метода конкретная реализация этого метода будет выбираться в соответствии с *динамическим типом* объекта, использованного в вызове. (Несмотря на наличие слова "динамический" в этом определении, динамическая память тут ни причем вообще.) В вашем случае

  ```
  Coder obj;
  Human *p = &obj;
  ```

  это означает, что в вызове

  ```
  p->Show();
  ```

  во время выполнения будет определен динамический тип объекта `*p`, выяснено, что это `Coder`, и, соответственно, будет вызван метод `Coder::Show()`. Вот и все. Никакой динамической памяти тут не нужно.

  (Разумеется, практические реализации этого механизма могут работать произвольным образом, обеспечивающим правильную функциональность. В традиционной реализации вы не увидите какого-то явного анализа динамического типа объекта, а увидите просто непрямой вызов через т.наз. *таблицу виртуальных методов*, но это дело десятое.)

  Фактически вы сами же правильно ответили и на этот вопрос: *"во время выполнения программы компилятор анализирует тип объекта, на который указывает указатель, чтобы определить какую реализацию виртуального метода следует вызвать"*. Но мне совершенно не ясно, почему вы из этого делаете вывод, что здесь необходимо какое-то участие динамической памяти.

Comment: Как я понял, динамический тип объекта позволяет определить во время выполнения программы на каком типе объекта необходимо вызвать виртуальный метод?

Comment: Т.е. при вызове виртуального метода, через указатель на базовый класс, компилятор обращается к таблице виртуальных методов базового класса (в которой каждый конкретный виртуальный метод связан через порядковые индексы со своими реализациями этого виртуального метода в таблице виртуальных методов класса-наследника), а из неё получает адрес тела виртуального метода класса-наследника, на динамическом типе объекта которого вызван этот виртуальный метод и после этого происходит его вызов?

Comment: @Brainsick: Ну да, все верно. С той только разницей, что в типичной реализации доступаясь к VMT объекта `*p` программа сразу попадает напрямую в правильную VMT класса-наследника и сразу берет оттуда правильный указатель на целевой метод. (Вполне может быть, что именно это вы и сказали выше.) То есть явно определять динамический тип не нужно. Но с абстрактно-концептуальной точки зрения все работает именно так.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под VMT? И как вообще возможно явно определить динамический тип? Ведь на то он и динамический

Comment: @Brainsick: Virtual Method Table - Таблица Виртуальных Методов.   В чем вы видите трудность определения *динамического типа* мне не ясно. *Динамический тип выражения* - это фактический тип объекта, на который это выражение ссылается. В данном примере, несмотря на то, что указатель `p` объявлен с типом `Human *`, *динамический тип* выражения `*p` - это `Coder`. А уж как его определить - это забота компилятора. (На практике он обычно определяется через посредство той же VMT. Можно сказать, что по тому, куда именно указывает VMT-указатель объекта, уже можно назвать динамический тип объекта.)

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что вызов виртуального деструктора также можно отнести к позднему связыванию, ибо удаление производного объекта происходит через указатель на базовый класс и виртуальный деструктор будет вызван из того класса, объектом которого инициализирован этот указатель. Используются ли при этом таблицы виртуальных методов? Или они только для вызова виртуальных методов предназначены? Просто механизмы вызова виртуальных методов и виртуальных деструкторов похожи.

Comment: @Brainsick: Обычно вызов виртуального деструктора реализуется абсолютно тем же механизмом, что и все остальные методы, т.е. да - это обычный метод в таблице виртуальных методов.

Comment: "Обычно вызов виртуального деструктора реализуется абсолютно тем же механизмом, что и все остальные методы" - т.е. что и все остальные **виртуальные** методы?

Comment: @Brainsick: Да,  что и все остальные *виртуальные* методы. Функции на деструктор возлагаются расширенные, но механизм виртуального вызова у него - как у обычного виртуального метода.

Answer (score 4):

В этих предложениях вы явно удаляете объекты, адресуемые указателями

```
delete human;
delete coder;
```

В каком порядке вы запишите эти предложения, в таком порядке и будут удаляться объекты. Если, например, вы запишите эти предложения как

```
delete coder;
delete human;
```

то сначала будет удален объект, адресуемый указателем `coder`, а затем будет удален объект, адресуемый указателем `human`. Эти объекты никак не связаны между собой, поэтому удаление одного объекта не влияет на время жизни другого объекта и его удаление.

> И фраза "уничтожение объекта базового класса влечет за собой
>   уничтожение объекта производного класса" касается только когда речь
>   заходит о полиморфизме?

Эта фраза не имеет никакого смысла.

> В связи с чем вопрос - почему создание объекта в автоматической памяти
>   считается корректным для реализации полиморфизма?

Этот вопрос также бессмысленным. Полиморфизм не связан с тем, в какой памяти создаются объекты.

В этом фрагменте кода

```
Human h("Tom", 21, 'M');
Human *human = &h;
Coder c("Alice", 19, 'F', 150.6f);
Human *coder = &c;
human->Show();
coder->Show();
```

указатель с именем `coder` типа `Human *`  указывает на объект производного класса типа `Coder`, и так как класс имеет виртуальную функцию, которая вызывается, используя указатель на базовый класс, то имеет место полиморфизм. Это никак не связано с созданием и удалением самих объектов.

Порядок удаления объекта описывается следующей цитатой из стандарта C++ (12.4 Destructors)

> 8 After executing the body of the destructor and destroying any
>   automatic objects allocated within the body, a destructor for class X
>   calls the destructors for X’s direct non-variant non-static data
>   members, the destructors for X’s direct base classes and, if X is the
>   type of the most derived class (12.6.2), its destructor calls the
>   destructors for X’s virtual base classes. All destructors are called
>   as if they were referenced with a qualiﬁed name, that is, ignoring any
>   possible virtual overriding destructors in more derived classes. Bases
>   and members are destroyed in the reverse order of the completion of
>   their constructor (see 12.6.2). A return statement (6.6.3) in a
>   destructor might not directly return to the caller; before
>   transferring control to the caller, the destructors for the members
>   and bases are called. Destructors for elements of an array are called
>   in reverse order of their construction

Что касается создания и удаления объектов с автоматической длительностью памяти, то (6.6 Jump statements)

> 2 On exit from a scope (however accomplished), objects with automatic
>   storage duration(3.7.3) that have been constructed in that scope are
>   destroyed in the reverse order of their construction.

Поэтому в этом фрагменте кожа

```
Human h("Tom", 21, 'M');
Human *human = &h;
Coder c("Alice", 19, 'F', 150.6f);
Human *coder = &c;
human->Show();
coder->Show();
```

сначала будет создан объект `h`, затем будет создан объект `c`, Удаление этих объектов будет произвежено в обратном порядке, то есть сначала будет удален объект `c`, а за ним будет удален объект `h`.

Comment: Понял, динамическое выделение памяти и динамический тип объекта это разные вещи.
Вопросы не совсем по теме,но все-же:

1) В каких случаях предпочтительнее создавать объект в автоматической памяти, а в каких - в динамической? Т.е. в статической если важна скорость размещения, а в динамической если объект больших размеров?

2) При ответе на другой мой вопрос вы дали определение таблицы указателей на виртуальные методы, наткнулся на понятие "таблица указателей на объекты" (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Динамическая_идентификация_типа_данных) случайно не знаете что под этим подразумевается?

Comment: @Brainsick Обычно в динамической памяти создают объекты, когда полная информации о них становится известна лишь во время выполнения программы. Также в динамической памяти создают объекты, когда необходимо, чтобы жизнь объекта не зависела от области определения, где создан объект. Что касается второго вопроса, то это техническая реализация идентификации объектов с использованием указателей на объекты.